# Responsive and Sticky Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, nav, sticky

I have a nav bar that is fixed to the top of the page when the width is under 768px.

When it is over 768px it starts at the bottom and when the user scroll past it it become stuck to the top.

Both of these instance work fine on their own, but when the browser is resized there are some issues when going from under 768px to above. (Going from 768 to below works fine.)

When I load the page in a browser size under 768px and then resize the window above that is where I run in to problems.

I would like for the nav bar to smoothly transition between states. (It works beautifuly when loading above 768px then reszing to under and reszing above - Ideally this is how I would like it to work when loaded below 768px.) Or as an alternative just have the nav bar be fixed to the top when moving from under 768px to above.

[This is the link to the site.](http://kyle-morrison.com/interzone/)

This is my CSS

```
.header{
width: 100%;
min-width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding: 0px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 99999;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

.header.fixed{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.header{
width: 100%;
background: black;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
}
```

and this is the Javascript

```
<script>  

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var s = jQuery(".header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("fixed"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have also tried below to no luck.

```
<script>  
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 768) {       
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var s = jQuery(".header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("fixed"); 
        }
    });
});
}</script>

<script>  
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 768) {       
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var s = jQuery(".header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("fixed"); 
        }
    });
});
}})</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function sticky_navigation() {
    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the page, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
    // otherwise change it back to relative
    if ((scroll_top > $('.header').height()) && (browserWidth > 720)) { 
        $('.header').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'z-index':999999, 'opacity': 0.9, 'box-shadow': '0px 3px 5px #393939' });
    } else {
        $('.header').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'opacity': 1, 'box-shadow': 'none' }); 
    }   
};

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});

// and run every time you resize to boot
$(window).resize(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this does not work at all. I will try and play around with that function though.